# Generics, Comparators, and Test Cases

Tags: java, generics

This assignment is part of a section on generics for my Java class. I think I'm having issues wrapping my head around generality by making it too general. For this particular class I have to implement a min (and several other) methods for whatever generic Collection I am given and use the given comparator (comp) to evaluate them.

Implemented code:

```
public static <T> T min(Collection<T> c, Comparator<T> comp)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchElementException {
        if (c != null && comp != null) {
            if (!c.isEmpty()) {
                T min = (T) null;

                for (T t : c) {
                    if (min == null) {
                        min = t;
                    } else if (comp.compare(t, min) < 0) {
                        min = t;
                    }
                }

                return min;

            } else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

My issue is I don't know how to test this method with my one comparators. I'll explain what I've read/how I understood it, and it'd be great if you guys could tell me where I'm missing something.

If I want to compare within a class (add my own compare/compareTo method):

```
public class Example<T extends Comparator<T>> {

}
```

If I want to write my own separate class as a comparator:

```
public class ExampleComp<T> implements Comparator<T> {
    @override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
    //do fancy things here
    }
}
```

That means that the way I should write test cases would be to implement my own comparator class and pass the `new ExampleComp()` as a variable in my method call.

So if my understanding of that is all correct, how do I write the test case for comparing anything and everything? Collection is supposed to be as general as possible, so how do I implement methods to compare one piece to another while keeping everything typesafe?

Comment: For _testing_, you need to test with a concrete class and a concrete comparator, not a general thing.  Your _implementation_ should be generic, but your tests can't be.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So do I just cast the <T> into int, string, etc? And compare like you usually would with those?

Comment: More or less, yes.  (You can't use a primitive `int`, though, just a boxed `Integer`.)

Comment: Gotcha. So basically I have a ton of testing ahead of me. Thanks Louis

Comment: I'd suggest reading the generics parts and tips on implementing your own comparable in Effective Java 2nd Edition book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, all your types are invariant. `Collection<T>` is a collection with a component type of T. A `List<T>` will match this type, but a Collection won't. There are two other possible component definitions using wildcards, which are *covariant* (`<? extends T>`) and *contravariant* (`<? super T>`) component types.

In your case, we could make the Collection covariant, but that would mean that your result type would hinge on the Comparator type. Thus the preferred solution is to make the Comparator contravariant. Your method then becomes:

```
public static <T> T min(Collection<T> c, Comparator<? super T> comp)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchElementException {…}
```

This works, because our comp will take any Comparator that compares at least a supertype of T. So if you have a `class Person` and a subclass `VeryIncompetentPerson`, a `Comparator<Person>` will be enough to get the minimum from a Collection of very incompetent persons.